# Dropdown form with selected value from variable

Tags: php, html

I have the current theme for my script stored in my config file (JQUERY_THEME) how can i make that the preselected value in the dropdown list.

```
$jquerytheme = JQUERY_THEME;
$themes = array("base", "black-tie", "blitzer", "cupertino", "dark-hive", "dot-luv", "eggplant", "excite-bike", "flick", "hot-sneaks", "humanity", "le-frog", "mint-choc", "overcast", "pepper-grinder", "redmond", "smoothness", "south-street", "start", "sunny", "swanky-purse", "trontastic", "ui-darkness", "ui-lightness", "vader");

echo "<p><select name=\"jquerytheme\">";
    foreach ($themes as $value) {
       echo "<option value=\"$value\">". ucfirst($value) . "</option>";
    }
echo "</select></p>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a option preselected you must use the `selected` attribute in the option:

```
echo "<p><select name=\"jquerytheme\">";
    foreach ($themes as $value) {
       $selected = ($value == $jquerytheme) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
       echo "<option $selected value=\"$value\">". ucfirst($value) . "</option>";
    }
echo "</select></p>";
```